# Auto filled form in Chrome on iOS not valid with Angular 5

Tags: google-chrome, angular5

I have an Angular 5 app with a login form. On iOS version 11.3 with Chrome the form auto fills the email and password fields but the form fails validation.

However, this works fine in Safari on the same device.

It also works fine in all browsers on Android.

I have tried two different ways of creating the form and both have the same behavior.

**Method 1**

```
<ngx-loading [show]="isLoading"></ngx-loading>
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-12">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <form class="form-signin" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                <input autofocus class="form-control" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email address" type="email" formControlName="email">
                <div *ngIf="form.controls.email.touched && form.controls.email.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password">
                <div *ngIf="form.controls.password.touched && form.controls.password.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Required</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-gold btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid || isLoading">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2**

```
<ngx-loading [show]="isLoading"></ngx-loading>
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-center col-12">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <form class="form-signin" name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
                <input autofocus class="form-control" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email address" type="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" required>
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !email.valid" class="text-danger">Required</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" type="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required>
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="text-danger">Required</div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-gold btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="isLoading">Sign in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Encountering the same issue.